# Matching in Python lists when there are extra characters

Tags: python, sorting, matching

I am trying to write a python code to match things from two lists in python.

One tab-delimited file looks like this:

`COPB2`

`KLMND7`

`BLCA8`

while the other file2 has a long list of similar looking "names", if you will.  There should be some identical matches in the file, which I have succeeded in identifying and writing out to a new file.  The problem is when there are additional characters at the end of one of the "names".  For example, `COPB2` from above should match `COPB2A` in file2, but it does not.  Similarly `KLMND7` should match `KLMND79`.  Should I use regular expressions?  Make them into strings? Any ideas are helpful, thank you!

What I have worked on so far, after the first response seen below:

```
with open(in_file1, "r") as names:
for line in names:
    file1_list = [i.strip() for i in line.split()]
    file1_str = str(file1_list)

with open(in_file2, "r") as symbols:
for line in symbols:
    items = line.split("\t")
    items = str(items)
    matches = items.startswith(file1_str)
    print matches
```

This code returns `False` when I know there should be some matches.

Comment: So did the code in your edit work for you?

Comment: Are both files tab delimited?  Maybe you could post sample files.  Are the files multiline?  Do you want matches that match symbols on any line in file2, or just the same line?

Comment: Yes, both are tab delimited, I would like matches that match symbols on any line.  Files are rather large, I will work on smaller sample files

Comment: If you have multiple tab-delimited items on each line, and multiple lines, is there any meaning attached to a line? That is, given a file `"foo\tbar\nbaz\tquux"`, would you want to match all four words equally, or do `foo` and `bar` need to be located together in some way in the other file in order to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.startswith()` No need for regex, if it's only trailing characters

```
>>> g = "COPB2A"
>>> f = "COPB2"
>>> g.startswith(f)
True
```

Here is a working piece of code:

```
file1_list = []
with open(in_file1, "r") as names:
    for line in names:
        line_items = line.split()
        for item in line_items:
            file1_list.append(item)

matches = []
with open(in_file2, "r") as symbols:
    for line in symbols:
        file2_items = line.split()
        for file2_item in file2_items:
            for file1_item in file1_list:
                if file2_item.startswith(file1_item):
                    matches.append(file2_item)
                    print file2_item
print matches
```

It may be quite slow for large files.  If it's unacceptable, I could try to think about how to optimize it.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work well when just comparing one name to one other. I am having trouble putting it in a loop.

Comment: You should post this code in the main question, so it's easier to parse.

Comment: Thanks so much! That code is a big help.  Also, to write the output to a file, would you just do something like `outputfile.write('\t'.join(matches))`  ??

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at difflib if you need a more generic solution. Keep in mind it is a big import with lots of overhead so only use it if you really need to. Here is another question that is somewhat similar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209800/difference-between-two-strings-in-python-php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you loaded the files into lists X, Y.

```
## match if a or b is equal to or substring of one another in a case-sensitive way
def Match( a, b):
    return a.find(b[0:min(len(a),len(b))-1])

common_words = {};
for a in X:
    common_words[a]=[];
    for b in Y:
        if ( Match( a, b ) ):
             common_words[a].append(b);
```

If you want to use regular expressions to do the matching, you want to use "beginning of word match" operator "^".

```
import re
def MatchRe( a, b ):        
    # make sure longer string is in 'a'.
    if ( len(a) < len(b) ):
         a, b = b, a;
    exp = "^"+b;
    q = re.match(exp,a);
    if ( not q ):
       return False; #no match
    return True; #access q.group(0) for matches
```